# Evaluate double integral using trapezoidal rule (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I have an assignment to evaluate a double integral using trapezoidal rule. The first part was to evaluate a double integral using trapezoidal rule with limits 
0 <= x <= 2, 0 <= y <= 1

I have a working script for that:

```
N = 100;
xh= 1.25;
x = linspace(0,2,N);
y = linspace(0,1,0.5*N);
dx = diff(x(1:2));
dy = diff(y(1:2));
[x,y] = meshgrid(x,y);
funk = exp(-10.*((x-xh).^2+y.^2)).*cos(y.*(x-xh));
funk(2:end-1,:) = funk(2:end-1,:)*2;
funk(:,2:end-1) = funk(:,2:end-1)*2;
out = sum(funk(:))*dx*dy/4;

disp(out)
```

Now for the second part the limits are 0 <= x <= 2, 0 <= y <= ((pi*x)/2)

How do I get y (line 4 in code) to take corresponding x values from the x-matrix to create the y-matrix? If I get that to work I shouldn't have to change anything else in the code right, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting problem.  Imagine a grid where the `x` coordinates span from `0 <= x <= 2` and the `y` coordinates span from `0 <= y <= pi`.  This is because when `x = 2`, then `y = pi*2/2 = pi`.

Now imagine drawing a line with a positive slope of `pi/2` from the origin up to `(x,y) = (2,pi)`.  The values of `(x,y)` you want to focus on are the **bottom right** of the grid.

To do that, simply create a `meshgrid` where `x` spans from `[0,2]` and `y` spans from `[0,pi]`, then choose the bottom right of the grid.  Assuming a grid of 100 x 100 points:

```
%// Generate grid of points
N = 100;
xx = linspace(0,2,N);
yy = linspace(0,pi,N);
[x,y] = meshgrid(xx,yy);

%// Obtain valid region
ind = y <= (pi/2)*x;

%// Show valid region in black and white
imagesc(ind);
axis xy;
colormap gray;
set(gca,'XTick',10:10:100);
set(gca,'YTick',10:10:100);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',xx(10:10:end));
set(gca,'YTickLabel',yy(10:10:end));
```

This is the figure we get:

[image]

The region in white is the region we are after.  `ind` contains a `logical` matrix that will allow us to select which values within our `meshgrid` we need to select.  As such, your code now is simply this:

```
%// Generate grid of points
N = 100;
xh = 1.25;
xx = linspace(0,2,N);
yy = linspace(0,pi,N);
[x,y] = meshgrid(xx,yy);

%// Obtain valid region
ind = y <= (pi/2)*x;

%// Perform calculations with normal grid
dx = diff(xx(1:2));
dy = diff(yy(1:2));
funk = exp(-10.*((x-xh).^2+y.^2)).*cos(y.*(x-xh));
funk(2:end-1,:) = funk(2:end-1,:)*2;
funk(:,2:end-1) = funk(:,2:end-1)*2;

%// Select out valid region coordinates
funk = funk(ind);

%// Now sum
out = sum(funk(:))*dx*dy/4;
```

For `out`, I get:

```
>> out

out =

         0.156821355105871
```

Comment: First of all, I have some additional information now. The correct answer should be out ≈ 0.156. With your code I get out = 0. And from what I can understand the area should be a part of a sinus curve, think the "hill". I see your logic though.

Comment: @MarkJansson Fixed. I used the wrong variables for `diff`. I got 0.1568 as my answer. I've edited my answer. Please check it.

Comment: @MarkJansson - Great :) If you don't mind, consider accepting my answer.  That tells the StackOverflow community that you no longer need help.  This can be done by clicking on the checkmark icon at the top of my post, to the left below the up and down arrow buttons.  Good luck!